# how can i show position of item clicked in customized listview

Tags: android, listview

I have used a custom listview to display images and also text information in my listview using hashmap and two xml layouts, of which one contains the listview and the other contains the custom row. And the code below works just fine. How should I toast the position of the row a user clicks ??

```
public class MainTopic  extends Activity{

ListView mtopiclv;
LinearLayout header;
List<HashMap<String, String>> rowList;

String[] topicHeader ={
        "What is farming ?",
        "Raising animals ?",
        "How to graz ?",
        "sdsdsdsd sdsd",
        "Control",
        "Find product centers",
        "Research and statistics",
        "How to succeed in sdfsdfds ?"
};
String[] info = {
        "Introduction, benefits",
        "Seeds, planting and care",
        "Requirements, , resources",
        "Investing in farming",
        "Practices and tools",
        "machinery",
        "books",
        "Business tips"
};  

int[] images = {
        R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2,
        R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4,
        R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6,
        R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_8
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mtopic);
    setUp();
    hashmap();
}
private void hashmap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    rowList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //looping through all items
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
        HashMap<String, String> infoList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        infoList.put("topicHeader", topicHeader[i]);
        infoList.put("info", info[i]);
        infoList.put("imgs", Integer.toString(images[i]));
        rowList.add(infoList);

        //from 
        String[] from = {"topicHeader", "info", "imgs"};
        int[] to = {R.id.clvHeader, R.id.clvsum, R.id.imgbtn};

        //adapter
        SimpleAdapter clvAdapter = new SimpleAdapter
        (getApplicationContext(), rowList, R.layout.mtopic_custome_lv, from, to);
        mtopiclv.setAdapter(clvAdapter);

    }
}
private void setUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mtopiclv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mtopiclv);
    header = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try to use setOnItemClickListener on listview

```
mtopiclv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {     

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();

    }
```

});

Comment: Its not returning the position

Comment: is it returning  list item index such 0,1,2 when u click on list item

Comment: it not returning anything, it doesn't even highlight the row I click

Comment: are you not getting any toast message from it. first check onItemClick method is executing or not

Comment: @williamjingo you need to close the for loop after `rowList.add(infoList)`. also use activity context instead of `getApplicationContext()` in your SimpleAdapter

Comment: mtopiclv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View arg1, int position,
     long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });

Comment: did you add your into oncreate method